# Google Drive API (PHP) - parents null

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the parent id of a file using the Google Drive API. My code is below:

```
$file_parent = $service->files->get($id);
var_dump($file_parent);
```

Unfortunately the parent object in the result is 'null' but I know it has a parent folder and I have permissions to view this. Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: What is `$id`? Is that null too?

Comment: Sorry the $id comes from another bit of my code which comes from the API using a search. the get() function does find the correct file I want, it's just the parents object is null

Answer (score 8):

Ah solved this one myself. You have to pass through the folowing:

```
$optParams = array(
    'fields' => "name, parents",
);
$file_parent = $service->files->get($parent, $optParams);
var_dump($file_parent);
```

Google aren't very clear about this!